# Sorting list of objects according the changeable object field

Tags: java, sorting

I have a Product list. I want to sort the products decreasingly according to their quantities.

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    int quantity;
    Product(String name, int quantity) {
        this.name=name;
        this.quantity=quantity
    }
}
```

By default there are 4 Products in the list with 0 quantity.

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList();
products.add(new Product("Book",0));
products.add(new Product("Table",0));
products.add(new Product("Chair",0));
products.add(new Product("Pen",0));
```

Also, quantities can be incremented or decremented one by one by the user from the web UI (by clicking a increment or decrement button which are located besides of every product)

For example, if user increment the "Pen" product quantity, then the "Pen" product should be relocated to top of the list .

Every, increment or decrement process, I need to re-sort the list. However, running a sorting algorithm every increment or decrement process is very inefficient especially if there are a lot of items in the list.

I haven't use any sorting algorithm yet. But I believe that, if there are too many items in the list and an increment occurred only one product, then all list have to be sorted again. I think, this is inefficient so I am asking that is there another way for this kind of problem.

So, how can sort these kind of a list?

Comment: What language is this ? Where is the code for sorting (i'm assuming you have such code and you have benchmarked it and found it to be 'slow')?

Comment: @auburg it is Java. I haven't use any sorting algorithm yet. But I believe that, if there are too many items in the list and an incrementation occured only one product, then all list have to be sorted again. I think, this is inefficient so I am asking that is there another way for this kind of problem.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/ - unless you're going to have literally several hundred thousand products then it's pointless even worrying about performance. Re-sorting for a few products each time would have a negligible runtime cost.

Comment: Only if you have problems should you worry about optimization, and then only after profiling.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 way of sorting a list. Internally it is merge sort.

```
    products.sort(Comparator.comparing(Product::getQuantity).reversed());
```

OR

```
    products.sort(Comparator.comparing(Product::getQuantity, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Stream Example

```
products.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Product::getQuantity, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a `sort` method in the `Collections` class and can sort products with `ASC` order like:

```
Collections.sort(products, Comparator.comparing(Product::getQuantity));
```

And for `DESC`, we need to invoke the `reversed` method:

```
Collections.sort(products, Comparator.comparing(Product::getQuantity).reversed());
```